# Java downloader - downloading multiple files

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, download

I have created a Java program which can download one file using URL, however now I wish for it to download multiple files using multiple threads. Could I use the same method and loop over the list of URLs to get the files? Or could anyone recommend a way to go about it?

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code so we can see if it can be used in a multi-threaded way?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Post some code you already have and show where exactly are you stuck. Nobody is gonna write it for you, all you can get is advice, and only if you provide sufficient info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
void download(URL url){
    ...
}

void downloadAll(URL[] urls){
    for(URL url : urls){
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> download(url));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As @LouisF. mentioned the recommended way to solve this problem are `Executors` though. So instead of the simple example using `Thread`s , this would be the more proper, but aswell a bit more complex approach:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newChachedThreadPool();
for(URL url : urls)
    service.submit(() -> download(url);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by that sorry, it is creating the thread,is it doing anything else?

Comment: @b.d the idea is to simply wrap the routine for downloading the files into a separate method that only requires the most basic parameters and launch that method from within a thread. I've left the download-routine itself to you. The rest is just the most common way to solve this kind of parallel-execution-problem.

Comment: One should not use Thread directly but more Executors and Tasks. You can refer to Item 68 of effective Java (2nd Edition) and this link http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools.html for example

Comment: @LouisF. I just used that code since OP explicitly asked for a solution using Threads. Personally I'd prefer using Executors for this purpose aswell. I'll edit the answer to add that point.

Comment: I guess OP is looking for guidance about how to multithread a piece of code ! That is why I think the response is inappropriate

Comment: @LouisF. I was expecting a bit of a higher level of knowledge of OP, and a specific reason why he asked the question the way he did. Anyways I edited the question with your recommendation, in case you're right about OPs knowledge level.

Comment: Sounds a better approach to me :) removed downvote !